# Connection reset by peer / broken pipe by too many Postgres conncetions

Tags: postgresql, go, networking, connection-pooling, psql

Using `sqlx` with a couple concurrent connections I ran quickly into the issue of `Too many open connections`. Limiting `db.DB.MaxOpenConnections` got actually rid of the problem and activated the connection pooling I was hoping for.

Now on some machines we observe at a test, which tests exactly that the too many open connections doesn't happen a different error:

```
read tcp [::1]:54883->[::1]:5432: read: connection reset by peer
read tcp [::1]:54886->[::1]:5432: read: connection reset by peer
read tcp [::1]:54884->[::1]:5432: read: connection reset by peer
read tcp [::1]:54887->[::1]:5432: read: connection reset by peer
read tcp [::1]:54885->[::1]:5432: read: connection reset by peer
read tcp [::1]:54888->[::1]:5432: read: connection reset by peer
…
```

The Postgres logs don't reveal anything. Could it be possible that this happens on the network stack? What else can I do to debug this? I cannot reproduce it locally.

Comment: Are you using a global db handle? Or openning one per each request? Are you closing `*sql.Rows` as you should? Are you executing new queries while looping through `*sql.Rows`?

Comment: @mkopriva sqlx takes care of that. It's one db handle

Comment: What's the MAX number of connections that your postgres can accept? May be it's a real case.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz 50. If the problem would be at the end of Postgres, wouldn't I see error message sin the log?

Comment: The point here is to find when the issue occurs, in the middle of an established connection/transaction? Check CPU/memory usage at postgres and system logs there.

Comment: Doc (http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) on db.Query warns: `be sure to call rows.Close() to return the connection back to the pool`. Could it be the cause in your case?